# Area common to curves using integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

Alright so I had to find the area of the common region determined by $y>=x^{0.5}$ and $x^2+y^2<2$. And I proceeded like this -- 
[image]

But I'm not getting the expected answer, are there any flaws in my logic or approach? Please let me know friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is not correct, because the upper boundary of the integral $$\int_{x=0}^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{x} \, dx$$ is a vertical line at $x = \sqrt{2}$, not the arc of the circle centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt{2}$.  Therefore, you cannot use this method to perform the area calculation; you have subtracted off an additional sliver-shaped area (shown in orange) outside the circle but underneath the parabola.

[image]

To get the correct area, you would need to locate the point of intersection of the circle and the parabola.  This corresponds to the solution of the system $$x^2 + y^2 = 2, \quad y^2 = x$$ in the first quadrant.  Then you can either split up the area of the shaded region, or you can express the shaded region as a difference of suitable areas, but in any case, you **must** use the fact that the two curves intersect at this point.

Fortunately, this point is simply $(1,1)$, so one direct method of calculation is to write $$A = \int_{x=0}^1 \sqrt{2-x^2} - \sqrt{x} \, dx.$$  Alternatively, we can write it as $$A = \frac{\pi}{4} - \int_{x=0}^1 \sqrt{x} - x \, dx,$$ if we recognize that the desired area is one eighth of the area of the circle, minus a sliver-shaped region whose boundary is the parabola from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$, and the line $y = x$ on this same interval.  See the following picture:

[image]

Personally, I think this method is easiest from a computational perspective.

A third method is to do the integration along the $y$-axis:  $$A = \int_{y=0}^1 y^2 \, dy + \int_{y=1}^\sqrt{2} \sqrt{2-y^2} \, dy.$$  There are quite a number of different ways to go about the calculation, but all should yield $$\pi/4 - 1/6.$$

Comment: Got the intersection point as $(1,1)$

Comment: How to get that small area.. Ugh im really racking my brain!

Comment: @Zlatan Don't think too hard about it.  Sometimes, the direct approach is the easiest.

Comment: @Zlatan The area enclosed between two functions $f(x) \ge g(x)$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is given by $$\int_{x=a}^b f(x) - g(x) \, dx.$$  The circle has equation $y = f(x) = \sqrt{2-x^2}$, and the parabola $y = g(x) = \sqrt{x}$.  This explains the first integral.  The second is similar, but with the choice $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) = x$.

Comment: What app did you use to sketch out that graph?

Comment: I precisely got what you told me man! Great job. Do you think this post deserves an upvote?It would be great for other people reviewing and doing the same mistake as me.

Answer (score 0):

The integral you wrote is the integral of $\sqrt{x}$ between the vertical lines $x=0$ and $x=\sqrt{2}$. This is *not* the same as the picture, which should integrate only between $x=0$ and the boundary of the circle. The easiest approach here is to convert to polar coordinates.

If you aren't familiar with polar coordinates, another approach is to divide up the computation of this area into two separate computations. By solving the equations $x^2+y^2=2$ and $y^2=x$ for $x$ you can see that the point of intersection of these two curves is the point $(1,1)$. Then the area of the region you want (the region *below* $y=\sqrt{x})$ is the sum of the area under $y=\sqrt{x}$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$ and the area under $x^2+y^2=2$ from $x=1$ to $x=\sqrt{2}$. Since $x^2+y^2=2$ is the same is $y = \sqrt{2-x^2}$ for $y\ge 0$, this gives
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}\,dx + \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{2-x^2}\,dx.$$

Comment: I did get what you're trying to say, the area under the straight line curve is just a little bit more than the boundary of circle, but I have no idea of complex numbers and polar coordinates.. If you could explain